# How do I get the current hour using Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I get the current hour in Cocoa using Objective-C?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To start off, you should read [Dates and Times Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039). That will give you a good understanding of using the various date/time/calendar objects that are provided in Cocoa for high-level conversions of dates.

This code snip, however, will answer your specific problem:

```
- (NSInteger)currentHour
{
    // In practice, these calls can be combined
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];

    return [components hour];
}
```

Comment: Better yet watch the WWDC videos and see this week's NSHipster

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
```

Answer (score 2):

I am new to Cocoa as well, and I am quite glad I found this. I also want to include that you can easily make this a function returning the current hour, minute and second in one NSDateComponents object. like this:

```
// Function Declaration (*.h file)
-(NSDateComponents *)getCurrentDateTime:(NSDate *)date;

// Implementation
-(NSDateComponents *)getCurrentDateTime:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit + NSMinuteCalendarUnit + NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    return comps;

}

// call and usage

NSDateComponents *today = [self getCurrentDateTime:[NSDate date]];
        hour = [today hour];
        minute = [today minute];
        second = [today second];
```

As you can see the components parameter in the NSCalendar object is a bit wise enum and you can combine the enum values using a '+'

Just thought I would contribute since I was able to use the examples to create mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSDate date]
```

That's the current time, parse out the hour as needed.  You didn't provide a lot of detail around exactly what hour you meant - formatted to a the current timezone for example?  Or a different one?

Answer (score 0):

Swift version

```
func currentHour() -> Int {
    let now = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.Hour, fromDate: now)

    return components.hour
}
```