# In Cocoa, how to obtain the current hours and minutes in an efficient way?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I want to display current time in my iPhone app using my own custom graphics.  What's the most efficient way to get the hours, minutes and seconds info?  I thought about using NSDateFormatter to get each part but this seems to be too CPU intensive.

Comment: Care to explain how you came to that conclusion with NSDateFormatter? I could imagine that changing the format string several times a second could seriously slow it down, but what if you used one formatter per component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use NSDateComponents.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070354/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-cocoa/1070412#1070412) on SO provides an example.

Comment: Also take a look at this answer on SO. It's a little more specific to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743140/how-do-i-get-the-current-hour-using-cocoa